# How do I stop Chrome changing the currency symbol on my web page?

Tags: html, google-chrome, localization

I have an application that writes out a report to an HTML page.  The report displays lots of lines with money values on it.

[image: Section of Report in MS Edge]

The report shows fine in IE and Edge but in Google Chrome all the currency symbols are changed from £ to Ł.

[image: Section of Report in Chrome]

I've done some testing and the raw html is being created correctly - with the £ symbol.

[image: Raw HTML]

If I remove some of the rows by hacking the raw HTML file then Chrome will revert to showing the correct symbol.

Therefore, I'm assuming Chrome is doing something that is possibly trying to 'guess' the locale of the data and getting it wrong.  Is there a way I can tell Chrome to show the data as it is without fiddling with it?

I have disabled all extensions in Chrome, and the report has no scripts/JS in it so can confirm this is default Chrome behaviour.

Sample report available here:  https://pastebin.com/nZ6reBWV

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<title>Report</title>
<style>
body { font: normal 13px helvetica, arial, sanserif; background-color:#fff; color:#000; line-height: 1.4em; margin: 20px 10px; }
hr { height: 1px; color: #1e427d; background-color: #1e427d; border: 0; }
table, th, td { border: none }
table { table-layout: fixed; width:100%; border: 0px solid #d8d8d8; border-bottom: none; margin-bottom: 1em; font: normal 13px arial}
td { font-size: 90%; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: .5em .3em; border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8; }
th { font-size: 90%; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding: .5em .3em; border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8; background-color: #d0d0d0;}
tr { background: #f8f8f8; color: #484848; }
td.data { text-align: center; }
tr.blank { background: #fff; color: #484848; }
tr.heading { background: #eaeaea; color: #484848; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<hr>
<table>
<th>

</th>
<th>
A1 25 Sportback 5Dr 1.0TFSI 95 SS S line Technology ST7
</th>
<th>
A1 25 Sportback 5Dr 1.0TFSI 95 SS Black Edition
</th>
<th>
A1 25 Sportback 5Dr 1.0TFSI 95 SS Black Edition ST7
</th>
<th>
A1 25 Sportback 5Dr 1.0TFSI 95 SS Black Edition Technology
</th>
<th>
A1 25 Sportback 5Dr 1.0TFSI 95 SS Black Edition Technology ST7
</th>
<th>
A1 25 Sportback 5Dr 1.0TFSI 95 SS S line
</th>
<tr class='heading'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>
Audi
</td>
<td class='data'>
Audi
</td>
<td class='data'>
Audi
</td>
<td class='data'>
Audi
</td>
<td class='data'>
Audi
</td>
<td class='data'>
Audi
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='heading'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>
A1
</td>
<td class='data'>
A1
</td>
<td class='data'>
A1
</td>
<td class='data'>
A1
</td>
<td class='data'>
A1
</td>
<td class='data'>
A1
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='heading'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>
25 Sportback 5Dr
</td>
<td class='data'>
25 Sportback 5Dr
</td>
<td class='data'>
25 Sportback 5Dr
</td>
<td class='data'>
25 Sportback 5Dr
</td>
<td class='data'>
25 Sportback 5Dr
</td>
<td class='data'>
25 Sportback 5Dr
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='heading'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>
1.0 T S Tr
</td>
<td class='data'>
1.0 T 
</td>
<td class='data'>
1.0 T S Tr
</td>
<td class='data'>
1.0 T 
</td>
<td class='data'>
1.0 T S Tr
</td>
<td class='data'>
1.0 T 
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='heading'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>
S line 1.0TFSI 95 GPF SS €6
</td>
<td class='data'>
Black Edition 1.0TFSI 95 GPF SS €6
</td>
<td class='data'>
Black Edition 1.0TFSI 95 GPF SS €6
</td>
<td class='data'>
Black Edition 1.0TFSI 95 GPF SS €6
</td>
<td class='data'>
Black Edition 1.0TFSI 95 GPF SS €6
</td>
<td class='data'>
S line 1.0TFSI 95 GPF SS €6
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Retail Price
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 24,365
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 22,920
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 24,460
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 24,615
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 26,155
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 21,130
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Delivery
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 660
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 660
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 660
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 660
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 660
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 660
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b>
P11D
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 25,025
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 23,580
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 25,120
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 25,275
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 26,815
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 21,790
</b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
CO2
</td>
<td class='data'>
137 g/km
</td>
<td class='data'>
133 g/km
</td>
<td class='data'>
140 g/km
</td>
<td class='data'>
133 g/km
</td>
<td class='data'>
140 g/km
</td>
<td class='data'>
130 g/km
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Annual Carbon Footprint (Tonnes)
</td>
<td class='data'>
5.07 tonnes
</td>
<td class='data'>
4.92 tonnes
</td>
<td class='data'>
5.18 tonnes
</td>
<td class='data'>
4.92 tonnes
</td>
<td class='data'>
5.18 tonnes
</td>
<td class='data'>
4.81 tonnes
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
BIK %
</td>
<td class='data'>
30 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
29 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
31 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
29 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
31 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
29 %
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
BIK Value
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 7,508
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 6,838
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 7,787
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 7,330
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 8,313
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 6,319
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Monthly BIK @ 20 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 125
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 114
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 130
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 122
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 139
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 105
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Monthly BIK @ 40 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 250
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 228
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 260
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 244
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 277
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 211
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Residual Value % (of P11d Value)
</td>
<td class='data'>
41.39 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
43.50 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
42.03 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
42.56 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
41.23 %
</td>
<td class='data'>
43.86 %
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b>
Residual Value
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 10,357
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 10,257
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 10,557
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 10,757
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 11,057
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 9,557
</b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Depreciation
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 14,668
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 13,323
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 14,563
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 14,518
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 15,758
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 12,233
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
SMR
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 1,834
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,126
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,126
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,153
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,153
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 1,834
</td>
</tr>

<td>
Insurance
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,838
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,967
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,838
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,967
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,838
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,967
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Finance
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,378
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,183
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,391
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,412
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,620
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,942
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Employer NI
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,212
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,929
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,328
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,139
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 3,552
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 2,706
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
VED
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 515
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 515
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 515
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 515
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 515
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 475
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Reg Fee
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 55
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 55
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 55
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 55
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 55
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 55
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Writing Down Allowance
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 1,062
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 1,000
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 1,066
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 1,072
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 1,138
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 924
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Corporation Tax Allowance
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 16,766
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 16,720
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 16,925
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 16,837
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 17,045
</td>
<td class='data'>
-£ 16,467
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
CPM
</td>
<td class='data'>
25.85 p
</td>
<td class='data'>
23.50 p
</td>
<td class='data'>
26.48 p
</td>
<td class='data'>
25.96 p
</td>
<td class='data'>
28.95 p
</td>
<td class='data'>
20.52 p
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Monthly
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 431
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 392
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 441
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 433
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 483
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 342
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Annual
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 5,170
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 4,701
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 5,296
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 5,191
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 5,790
</td>
<td class='data'>
£ 4,105
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<b>
Total
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 15,510
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 14,102
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 15,888
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 15,574
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 17,371
</b>
</td>
<td class='data'>
<b>
£ 12,315
</b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Data Source: Report
</td>
<td class='data'>
02 February 2021
</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Petrol
</td>
<td class='data'>
118.10 ppl
</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Diesel
</td>
<td class='data'>
122.70 ppl
</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Finance Rate
</td>
<td class='data'>
4.50 %
</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr class='blank'>
<td>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Corporation Tax Rate
</td>
<td class='data'>
26.00 %
</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
<td class='data'>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is putting an other symbol? To me, it seems a font/display problem. As you can see on second table, the alternate currency symbol is displayed in various manners. Try to change font and/or to increase size of cells, and check if the real problem is different

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Absolutely certain - the page displays correctly just by removing some lines from the report.  Also when doing 'show source' it displays the wrong character.

Comment: For the time being I appear to have hacked a solution by adding some text at the bottom of the page - taken from the company 'about us' page.  This appears to have 'fooled' chrome into knowing it is in English.  I'm almost certain this is an 'auto-translation' issue as I noticed Chrome was offering to translate from "Unknown" to "English" but adding the meta tags advised by google here https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/special-tags did not work to force no translation.

Comment: The browser singularity is coming!